# boost::condition_variable with boost::mutex::scoped_lock

Tags: boost, locking, boost-thread

Initially I was using `boost::mutex::scoped_lock` as such (which worked)

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_name); 
condition.wait(lock); //where condition = boost::condition_variable
```

However later I changed the lock to the following which does not work

```
boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_name)
condition.wait(lock); //Error
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue I get intellisense error stating `No instance of the overloaded function matches the argument list`. The compile error is

```
Error   7   error C2664: 'void boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<Mutex> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::lock_guard<Mutex>' to 'boost::unique_lock<Mutex> &'
```

Comment: just a point: you never KNOW that a concurrent algorithm works. unless you mathematically prove it. which cannot be done because the compiler and the hardware are not provable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::lock_guard` doesn't have `unlock` member-function, which is needed for `condition`. Use `unique_lock` instead:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
condition.wait(lock);
```

Comment: From what I have read is that unique_lock is more advanced than lock_guard. Will I have to make any further changes if I use unique_lock ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar Correct, `lock_guard` is a very trivial RAII locking facility, and its capabilities are insufficient for `condition`. You can use `lock_guard` with no additional changes - it's also RAII lock, but with additional functionality.